# apache axis2 com.ctc.wstx.exc.WstxUnexpectedCharException error

Tags: java, apache-axis

I working on a web service using apache `axis2`, I have generated client stub code from `wsdl` file how when I call the web service I'm getting this error:

```
org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: com.ctc.wstx.exc.WstxUnexpectedCharException: Unexpected character '"' (code 34) in DOCTYPE declaration; expected a space between public and system identifiers
 at [row,col {unknown-source}]: [1,50]
    at org.apache.axis2.AxisFault.makeFault(AxisFault.java:430)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.TransportUtils.createSOAPMessage(TransportUtils.java:123)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.TransportUtils.createSOAPMessage(TransportUtils.java:67)
    at org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.handleResponse(OutInAxisOperation.java:354)
    at org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.send(OutInAxisOperation.java:421)
    at org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.executeImpl(OutInAxisOperation.java:229)
    at org.apache.axis2.client.OperationClient.execute(OperationClient.java:165)
    at org.csapi.www.wsdl.parlayx.sms.notification_manager.v2_3.service.SmsNotificationManagerServiceStub.startSmsNotification(SmsNotificationManagerServiceStub.java:618)
    at org.csapi.www.wsdl.parlayx.sms.notification_manager.v2_3.service.Notification.startNotification(Notification.java:118)
    at org.csapi.www.wsdl.parlayx.sms.notification_manager.v2_3.service.Notification.main(Notification.java:39)
Caused by: org.apache.axiom.om.OMException: com.ctc.wstx.exc.WstxUnexpectedCharException: Unexpected character '"' (code 34) in DOCTYPE declaration; expected a space between public and system identifiers
 at [row,col {unknown-source}]: [1,50]
    at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.builder.StAXOMBuilder.next(StAXOMBuilder.java:296)
    at org.apache.axiom.soap.impl.builder.StAXSOAPModelBuilder.getSOAPEnvelope(StAXSOAPModelBuilder.java:198)
    at org.apache.axiom.soap.impl.builder.StAXSOAPModelBuilder.<init>(StAXSOAPModelBuilder.java:154)
    at org.apache.axiom.soap.impl.builder.StAXSOAPModelBuilder.<init>(StAXSOAPModelBuilder.java:140)
    at org.apache.axis2.builder.BuilderUtil.getSOAPBuilder(BuilderUtil.java:686)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.TransportUtils.createDocumentElement(TransportUtils.java:197)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.TransportUtils.createSOAPMessage(TransportUtils.java:145)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.TransportUtils.createSOAPMessage(TransportUtils.java:108)
    ... 8 more
Caused by: com.ctc.wstx.exc.WstxUnexpectedCharException: Unexpected character '"' (code 34) in DOCTYPE declaration; expected a space between public and system identifiers
 at [row,col {unknown-source}]: [1,50]I working on a web service using apache axis2, i have generated client stub code from wsdl file how when i call the web service i'm getting this error:
    at com.ctc.wstx.sr.StreamScanner.throwUnexpectedChar(StreamScanner.java:648)
    at com.ctc.wstx.sr.BasicStreamReader.startDTD(BasicStreamReader.java:2482)
    at com.ctc.wstx.sr.BasicStreamReader.nextFromPrologBang(BasicStreamReader.java:2398)
    at com.ctc.wstx.sr.BasicStreamReader.nextFromProlog(BasicStreamReader.java:2058)
    at com.ctc.wstx.sr.BasicStreamReader.next(BasicStreamReader.java:1069)
    at org.apache.axiom.util.stax.wrapper.XMLStreamReaderWrapper.next(XMLStreamReaderWrapper.java:225)
    at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.builder.StAXOMBuilder.parserNext(StAXOMBuilder.java:668)
    at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.builder.StAXOMBuilder.next(StAXOMBuilder.java:214)
    ... 15 more
```

Any idea on what could wrong with my code?

Comment: Have you tried intercepting the XML as it is being sent between the components? Wireshark works well with this.

Comment: I've run into the same problem, and apparently there are a number of others who have as well, but I'm not finding any silver bullets. The only possible hint I've found [here](http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/axis-java-user/201006.mbox/%3CBLU142-W370CC9EC14CCF880F84E6AED20@phx.gbl%3E) indicates that "wstx expects the character to be a valid IsoControl character".

Comment: Have you got the solution for this issue ?

Answer (score 1):

Check for the address and port in the endpoint in the wsdl.

```
<wsdl:port binding="" name="">
  <soap:address location=""/>
</wsdl:port>
```

Generate the client again and try calling the web service.

Answer (score 1):

Which encoding are you using and what encoding is on your received text? `wstx expects the character to be a valid IsoControl character` suggests you're using ISO in your system and maybe receiving UTF-8 or some other incompatible encoding. Make sure encodings match and there should be no problem.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes I get this error when the application with WSDL file (the service that you are trying to reach) is not deployed properly.